# How to Import custom typescript in a react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have this following project structure.

```
src/
├── components
│   └── workspace
│       ├── DialogBox.jsx
│       ├── index.js
│       ├── prepareDevNetwork.js
│       ├── ToolBar.jsx
│       └── Workspace.jsx
├── engine
│   ├── service.ts
│   └── index.ts
```

```
index.ts - 
export { foo } from './service';
```

```
service.ts - 
export function foo(){/*do something*/}
```

I'm trying to import foo as follows

`import { foo } from '../../engine'`

I'am getting `unable to resolve path to module ../../engine`

Comment: how did your ts file export?

Comment: sorry didn't get you,

Comment: if you want to import something, you need to export it from somewhere.  Which method is your ts files using to export. ```export``` or ```export default``` ? Here is a article you can read

https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910